# Codeigniter 4: Cannot access the page with apache mode_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I installed Codeigniter 4.0.0.rc3 on my local computer using Wampserver and created a 'people' controller. I can access the page using this address:

> http://127.0.0.1/election/index.php/people

But not without 'index.php':

> http://127.0.0.1/election/people

And this is the error:

> The requested URL /Projects/Web/election/public/index.php/people was not found on this server.

**.htaccess is in the public directory and is working because the error shows index.php in the path.**

This is my htaccess:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

**UPDATE:** This htacces is working perfectly on a Linux Host but not working with Wampserver on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

In linux apache2 the following works, should be applicable to wampp's apache as well:

1. Make sure mode_rewrite is enabled
2. Edit your public .htaccess file as follows:

   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

(would appreciate if someone explains the QSA statement)

3. In app/Config/App.php edit:

   `public $indexPage = 'index.php';`

to

```
public $indexPage = '';
```

Comment: My htacces is working perfectly on a Linux Host but not working with Wampserver on Windows 10

Comment: Same here, I am having a real hardtime making the rewrite rule works in WAMP (EasyPHP with PHP 7.4.5 to be exact)

Answer (score 0):

I had to play around a lot before I figured it out, but I had installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder. (I access the website via http://127.0.0.1/myapp/).

I had configured the $baseURL parameter in the config file, but I kept getting that apache error. Just like you, if I added the /index.php in the URL, all my routes were working fine.

In /public/.htaccess, The QSA option didn't help, but this section just above did:

> # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
>       # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
>       # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
>       RewriteBase /myapp/

Adding this allow mod_rewrite to work fine. Obviously you need to change /myappp/ to what your virtual subfolder is, in order for it to match the subfolder portion of the $baseURL parameter in Config/App.php

Hope this help !