# 403 Forbidden in Vue.js + CodeIgniter 4

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, codeigniter

I created a simple api using CodeIgniter 4 that currently has 2 routes :

```
$routes->get('/expenses','Home::getAllExpenses');
$routes->post('/expenses','Home::addRecord');
```

I display the data using Vue, so the first one returns some json data about expenses while the second one should store the data from a form.

What happens is when I hit submit I get a 403 Forbidden for the post route.

The call is made like this:

```
this.validationError = false;
                this.request.sum = this.sum;
                this.request.type = this.type;
                this.request.name = this.name;

                this.$http.post(base_api_url + 'expenses', this.request)
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

The get request is ok and nothing on the CI forum helped me :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you check to see if your POST requests  also includes cookies (in developer tools > network tab)? It's a fairly common problem that fetch/xhr libraries (like this.$http) do not send credentials (cookies) by default. If the cookies are missing from your, you can enable sending credentials by:

```
Vue.http.options.credentials = true;
```

Assuming you are using Vue-resource (this.$http)

Comment: Yes, it does, it sends `csrf_cookie_name=52f093899d5fdf23fbee373a19898de4`

Comment: And what is the url that is posted to?

Comment: `
Request URL: http://localhost/vuePLtracker/public/expenses
Request Method: POST
`

Comment: Right, is it possible that that should be localhost/vuePLtracker/expenses? Try opening the two urls in a new tab.

Comment: In CI4 you must specify the public folder, tried changing the form `action` url and still the same, 403 forbidden.

Comment: Allright, it may be an apache configuration issue (if you use apache). Is this a brand new CodeIgniter application / do you have other routes/apis/and stuff?

Comment: only the 2 routes above and the basic .htaccess file, clean install of xampp

Comment: Ok, I would suggest creating a some classic routes / classic form / posthandler first without Javascript/XHR first to verify/proof that your entire setup is as it should be. You could also try starting the application with `php spark serve`. I say this because the 'public' directory should be your the document-root of your app, so it should not appear in the url. Everything outside the public dir should never be exposed (you dont want people downloading all your projects configuration files for instance)...

Comment: called it from Postman and it shows all the files in the project....strange

Comment: oh, then it might be the webserver setup, a 403 HTTP error is shown if you try to list/access a directory. This may happen if apache's mod_rewrite isn't enabled or htaccess files arent allowed (the AllowOverride option in apache). In a good setup this wont happen, each request will be passed to CodeIgnitor (or serve static file)

Comment: Do you have an example of a good setup of any kind ?

Comment: You can start the application (webserver) via the command line using the command 'php spark serve'. But assuming you are using windows this is may not be an (easy) option. Maybe this thread is helpful, its about running CodeIgniter in a subfolder, like you are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890494/codeigniter-4-cannot-access-the-page-with-apache-mode-rewrite